# rank position based on field value

Tags: views

I would like to display the rank position of a node based on a field value.

Let's say that in field_A there is the node's quantity of "points" and in field_B the node's category.

Then, I would like to display that the current node is 5th out of 15 in its category for example.

thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: I don't know yet. Any idea?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking

Comment: can you write code, or do you need to do this as a view?

Comment: Whatever, view or code in a field (computed field) will be fine

Comment: If you want us to help you, you'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want. You can find different ways of handling ties in my wikipedia link above.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by handling ties. I have 2 fields in the node. Points and category. When  a node is displayed, I would like to display the position of the node out of the quantity of node in its category based on the number of points.

Comment: see wikipedia link

Comment: Thanks for the link Ollie.  Standard competition ranking ("1224" ranking). Is it what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

seems you need to create a "taxonomy view" (category) then create a listing and sort them by the "points" field value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need to show only the current node position.  With this method it displays all nodes

Comment: If you want to create a (table)list like:
1.node x
2.node y
3,node z

U can use the display field :global counter.

Jus showing one node can be done by filter or using a contextual filter.

Comment: The problem is that when U use a filter and so display 1 result,  the global counter will be always 1. It doesn't keep the rank that was before filtering.